# Value not get stored in my arrayList<data> when trying to fetch value from JSON Array by using Graph API

Tags: android, arrays, json

I want to display my facebook posts on my app.
So I stored the fetched value inside an `ArrayList<data>` and passed it to the next activity using `putParcelableArrayListExtra`.

But I am getting this Error from Logcat:

[image: Error from Logcat]

Here is my code for fetching the `JsonArray`:

```
GraphRequest(
  AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/posts", null, 
  HttpMethod.GET,
  GraphRequest.Callback { 
    response ->
      Log.e(TAG,response.toString())
  try {
    var json:JSONObject =response.jsonObject
    var jarray:JSONArray = json.getJSONArray("data");
    for( i  in 0 until jarray.length()){
       var mdataa:JSONObject = jarray.getJSONObject(i)
       var mMessage:String =mdataa.getString("message") 
       var mId:String =mdataa.getString("id")
       var mCreatedTime =mdataa.getString("created_time")
       mArrayList?.add(Data(mMessage,mId,mCreatedTime))
     }
  } catch ( e: JSONException) {
     e.printStackTrace()
  }
/*

*/
    var main:Intent =  Intent(this@Display, DisplayingPost::class.java)
    main.putParcelableArrayListExtra("data", mArrayList)
      startActivity(main)
  }
  ).executeAsync()
}
```

and the  code  which is used for receiving my value in another Activity:

```
var inBundle:Bundle = getIntent().getExtras()
var araayList:ArrayList<Data> =inBundle.getParcelableArrayList<Data> 
("data")
```

Sorry for bad English.
I am a beginner in Android:

Comment: It might be your parcelable data value is null.

Comment: yes its returning null when i check it through Toast how to fix it .i passed the required parameters inside the for loop using .add(). jarray is not returning null i checked for it .